# Postgres EXECUTE is slower than Query

Tags: postgresql, function, execute

I am facing a problem, I have developed a function with dynamic whare clause.
When every I run the query separatly it returns the value much faster while running with `EXECUTE` it give allot of time. 
 `"cv."SessionId" = ''f0d1c0e1-b13c-4aff-b1f7-432183b06d10'' AND cv."CampusId" = ''4f4310a3-9c36-49c2-8456-5604cb7e9a62'' AND cv."ProgramId"=''e50efffa-40a3-4eb9-a65b-65106967add7'' AND cv."ShiftId"=''414de073-ca8b-4a84-80bc-52c2030b4eeb'' AND cv."ProgramDetailId"=''8d1ce321-d015-4336-ba92-dcd2c8b6443b'' AND cv."ClassId"=''8931d744-acc9-4776-a03a-2b705038ea48'' AND cv."SectionId"=''83c507d0-8f61-4a28-b221-88625482953f'' AND cv."CollectorId"=''e58d2fbf-839a-49a1-b1ce-92e7c26a305b'' AND cv."FeeHeadId"=''5721bc8f-4e9c-49d0-a992-6b846fafb9db'' AND cv."PaidDate" >= ''2020-07-01'' AND cv."PaidDate" <= ''2020-08-07'' ORDER BY cv."ChallanNo" ASC"` 
 
 this is where clause parameter which change every time. some time two some time four or five. the following is my function which i want to optimize.

````
declare feeheadrow record;
declare paiddate date;
declare rollno text;
declare admisformid uuid;
declare feeheadname text;
declare instNo int4;
declare stdname text;
declare fathername text;
declare refno text;
declare classid uuid;
declare campusprogid uuid;
declare stdid uuid;
declare challano text;
declare campusid uuid;
declare sessionid uuid;
declare progdetailid uuid;
declare campusname text;
declare descrip text;
declare shiftname text;
declare genderid uuid;
declare shiftid uuid;
declare remarks text;
declare sessionname text;
declare totalamount int4;
declare programid uuid;

declare collectorid uuid;

    BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "FeeReport";
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "FeeHeads";

create temp table "FeeReport"("NewID" uuid, "PaidDate" Date, "RollNo" text, "AdmissionFormId" uuid, "FeeHeadName" text, "InstallmentNo" int4, "StudentName" text, "FatherName" text, "RefferenceNo" text, "ClassId" uuid, "CampusProgramId" uuid, "FeeHeadId" uuid,
"FeeAmount" int4, "PayableAmount" int4, "StudentId" uuid, "ChallanNo" text, "CampusId" uuid, "SessionId" uuid,
"ProgramDetailId" uuid, "CampusName" text, "Description" text, "ShiftName" text, "GenderId" uuid,
"ShiftId" uuid,"Remarks" text, "ScholarshipCriteriaId" uuid, "ScholarshipCriteriaName" text, "SessionName" text, "TotalAmount" int4
, "ProgramId" uuid, "CollectorId" uuid
) on commit DROP; 

create temp table "FeeHeads"("FeeHeadId" UUID, "FullName" TEXT) on commit drop;

insert into "FeeReport"
SELECT * FROM "Query"('cv.*', '"Fee"."VWFeeStatement2" AS cv', whereclause) AS
"FeeRecords" ("NewID" uuid, "PaidDate" date, "RollNo" text, "AdmissionFormId" uuid, "FeeHeadName" text, "InstallmentNo" int4, "StudentName" text, "FatherName" text, "RefferenceNo" text, "ClassId" uuid, "CampusProgramId" uuid, "FeeHeadId" uuid, "FeeAmount" int4, "PayableAmount" int4, "StudentId" uuid, "ChallanNo" text, "CampusId" uuid, "SessionId" uuid, "ProgramDetailId" uuid, "CampusName" text, "Description" text, "ShiftName" text, "GenderId" uuid, "ShiftId" uuid, "Remarks" text, "ScholarshipCriteriaId" uuid, "ScholarshipCriteriaName" text, "SessionName" text, "TotalAmount" int4,"ProgramId" uuid,"CollectorId" uuid);

insert into "FeeReport"
SELECT * FROM "Query"('cv.*', '"Fee"."VWFeeStatementOther2" AS cv', whereclause) AS
"FeeRecords" ("NewID" uuid, "PaidDate" date, "RollNo" text, "AdmissionFormId" uuid, "FeeHeadName" text, "InstallmentNo" int4, "StudentName" text, "FatherName" text, "RefferenceNo" text, "ClassId" uuid, "CampusProgramId" uuid, "FeeHeadId" uuid, "FeeAmount" int4, "PayableAmount" int4, "StudentId" uuid, "ChallanNo" text, "CampusId" uuid, "SessionId" uuid, "ProgramDetailId" uuid, "CampusName" text, "Description" text, "ShiftName" text, "GenderId" uuid, "ShiftId" uuid, "Remarks" text, "ScholarshipCriteriaId" uuid, "ScholarshipCriteriaName" text, "SessionName" text, "TotalAmount" int4,"ProgramId" uuid,"CollectorId" uuid);


insert into "FeeHeads"
SELECT DISTINCT fh."FeeHeadId", fh."FullName" FROM "Fee"."FeeHead" AS fh, "FeeReport" fr
WHERE fr."FeeHeadId" = fh."FeeHeadId";

FOR vwfeestatementrow in select distinct f."AdmissionFormId"
 from "FeeReport" f
LOOP
        select vw."PaidDate", vw."RollNo", vw."AdmissionFormId", vw."InstallmentNo", vw."StudentName", vw."FatherName" , vw."RefferenceNo", vw."ClassId", 
        vw."CampusProgramId", vw."StudentId", vw."ChallanNo", vw."CampusId" , vw."SessionId",
        vw."ProgramDetailId", vw."CampusName", vw."Description", vw."ShiftName", vw."GenderId",vw."ShiftId", vw."SessionName", vw."TotalAmount",vw."ProgramId",vw."CollectorId" 
        INTO paiddate,rollno,
        admisformid,instNo,stdname,fathername,refno,classid,
        campusprogid,stdid,challano,campusid,sessionid,progdetailid,campusname,descrip,shiftname,genderid,shiftid,sessionname,totalamount,programid,collectorid
        from "FeeReport" vw where vw."AdmissionFormId"=vwfeestatementrow."AdmissionFormId" limit 1;
        
      FOR feeheadrow IN SELECT fh."FeeHeadId",fh."FullName" FROM "FeeHeads" fh WHERE (fh."FeeHeadId" NOT IN (
      SELECT ins."FeeHeadId" FROM "FeeReport" AS ins WHERE ins."AdmissionFormId" = vwfeestatementrow."AdmissionFormId"))
        LOOP
        INSERT INTO "FeeReport"("NewID","PaidDate","RollNo","AdmissionFormId","FeeHeadName","InstallmentNo","StudentName",
        "FatherName","RefferenceNo","ClassId", "CampusProgramId","FeeHeadId",
        "FeeAmount", "PayableAmount", "StudentId", "ChallanNo", "CampusId", "SessionId",
        "ProgramDetailId", "CampusName", "Description", "ShiftName", "GenderId",
        "ShiftId","Remarks", "ScholarshipCriteriaId", "ScholarshipCriteriaName", "SessionName", "TotalAmount","ProgramId",
        "CollectorId"
        ) 
        VALUES(uuid_generate_v1(),paiddate,rollno,vwfeestatementrow."AdmissionFormId",
        feeheadrow."FullName",instNo,stdname,fathername
        ,refno,classid,campusprogid,feeheadrow.
        "FeeHeadId",0,0,stdid,challano,campusid,
        sessionid,progdetailid,campusname,descrip,shiftname,genderid,shiftid,'',null,'',
        sessionname,totalamount,programid,collectorid
        );
        
        END LOOP;

END LOOP;

-- DELETE FROM "Student" AS st WHERE st."AdmissionFormId" IN (SELECT af."AdmissionFormId" FROM "Fee"."StudentFeeStructure" AS sf, "Admission"."AdmissionForm" AS af WHERE sf."AdmissionFormId" = af."AdmissionFormId" AND af."CampusProgramId" = campusprogramid  AND sf."ConcessionDetailId" IS NOT NULL);

    RETURN query Select fr.* from "FeeReport" as fr ORDER BY fr."ChallanNo", fr."FeeHeadName";
END```
````

Comment: executing commands from text is a bad choice. it will be slow, it can't use any benefits of plan-catching or other optimizations. better try to workaround by using more variables.

Comment: Is there a way to create dynamic query or function without text form?